# First posts review should recognize actions taken before the review page

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activate “I'm Done” button in New Post Review queue if I have already acted on the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147086/activate-im-done-button-in-new-post-review-queue-if-i-have-already-acted-on-t)

In the new review panels, if you click through to the actual question, upvote the question, and then use the browser's back function to go to the review page, you can not select "I'm done." Even after a page refresh, the review page will show your upvote, but "I'm done" remains disabled.

I just encountered this while reviewing a first question.

Seems like clicking through to the question should be encouraged...

Comment: You can uondo and then redo your upvote.

Comment: This would be solved by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147086/activate-im-done-button-in-new-post-review-queue-if-i-have-already-acted-on-t

Comment: @Jim: Only until the vote is locked.

Comment: True. There is still the option to add a comment and then delete it.