# If you're quick, you can earn two review 'points' for one review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I appear to have earned a 'point' for a single review in two queues, by flicking quickly between queues:

[image]

and...

[image]

I don't mind much really, but this seems incorrect.

Comment: You mean you reviewed the same post twice? Once in each queue? I don't really see the problem with that... You reviewed the post as a late answer.. then you reviewed it as someone's first post.

Comment: In the second queue, I just clicked 'I'm Done'.

Comment: the fact that the "I'm done" button appeared on a post without you taking action might be the problem here. Why don't you outline the exact process in the post; exactly what/how it happened.

Comment: I flagged the item in one queue, clicked I'm done there, then went to the second queue.  The same item appeared, so I just had to click I'm Done.

Comment: @Geoff, why don't we just put a simple filter in and fix this problem.  It could stay in the other queue, just don't let the user see it, just like you wouldn't even if it stayed in the original queue.  Hitting one `I'm done` or `Skip` would record that response in each queue.  It's just so simple and easy.

Answer (score 18):

That's by design, though. If you get to review a post you already edited, the "I'm done" button is enabled by default. Doesn't matter if you are quick or not. Can be an edit that's a week old.

In fact it used to be that the button was *not* enabled in such cases, but people complained, and it was changed. Here is the feature request: [Activate “I'm Done” button in New Post Review queue if I have already acted on the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147086/activate-im-done-button-in-new-post-review-queue-if-i-have-already-acted-on-t).

Comment: I see. I'd rather not be asked to review something I've already reviewed though.  I think items I've hit 'Not Sure' for seem to come back sometimes too (no evidence).  Maybe they should say 'Are you really not sure?'

Comment: @martinclayton That change was made too.  You will no longer be shown items in the first/late posts (when going to a random or next post) that you have taken an action on.  However, if you have a link to a post in the queue already, and then take an action, the I'm done button will appear there.  Chances are you either loaded the late posts queue item first, or there was caching going on that resulted in you being given the item despite [very] recently taking an action on that post.

Answer (score 3):

It happens a lot of times to me, when there are not many **First posts** and **Late answers**. In my opinion, when you are reviewing a late answer and click <kbd>I'm done</kbd>, the same post in **First posts** should go away. It seems like a bug, not a feature.

Answer (score 1):

They should just filter it so we don't see posts that we've already reviewed.

Posts are already being filtered in the first queue that a user acknowledges it, so it would be simple to just filter it for that user in the other queues also.  Treat any `Skip` or `I'm Done` or any button-click for that matter as being done in all queues for that user.

If a post is completely removed from all queues, then any filtering would be reset.

You could also just exclude the Close/Reopen queues from the filtering if it was too complicated to reset the filtering, which would depend on your database structure and how you were currently handling the filtering that is already implemented.

Comment: Different queues... different tables possibly?

Comment: Sure, but they'll have the same question id, so they can filter on that.  In fact, I thought it was mentioned someplace they already do a little filtering so that a user gets questions on tags he's more familiar with.

Comment: Stop and think about this for a minute - which queues should this apply to? I doubt you'd want to miss a question you edited from First Posts if it later appeared in Reopen, for instance...

Comment: @Shog9, thanks, edited answer.