# Took an action on a post already but the First Posts review queue sometimes doesn't activate "I'm Done" button

Tags: support, review

Why does First Posts review queue fails to detect an action already taken on a post earlier? This doesn't seem to be the case with Late Answers review queue.

See the screenshots:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

- It's a Late Answers review queue. I didn't take an action earlier so no changes are detected, and hence <kbd>I'm done</kbd> not activated.

  [image]
- I closed the tab, visited that answer and commented on it, came back to review queue using browser history, and the queue detected my changes, and hence <kbd>I'm done</kbd> was shown activated.

  [image]
- In contrast, First Posts review queue likes to bug me. It didn't detect my flag raised on the post earlier, and hence, didn't activate <kbd>I'm done</kbd>.

  [image]
- It's not the first time this issue annoyed  me.

  [image]
- Usually, the changes are detected by First Posts review queue.

  [image]

Related: [Activate “I'm Done” button in New Post Review queue if I have already acted on the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147086/286110).

Comment: If my observations are correct, the queues only recognize prior actions if you a) load the queue entry; b) take the action; c) load the queue entry again. If you deviate from that sequence, all bets are off.

Comment: I do that deviation part most of the time. The fourth image is what depicts that action taken on a post prior to reviewing it and it is usually detected by the system and relevant buttons lit up during review.