# The browser's "Back" button cause problems with the review buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, back-button

These are the steps to reproduce what I noticed.

- I clicked on the link to review the suggested edits, and I was given https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/851165 as post to review
- I clicked on "Skip" to pass to the next
- I was taken to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/851166
- I clicked on "improve" by mistake
- When I noticed that, I clicked on the back button to go out of the edit page

After I did that, I was shown the previous post to review, but in that page the review buttons didn't work. What I described happens even in the case the suggested edit is already approved/rejected; in that case the "next" button doesn't work.

Is this a bug, or is it expected to happen?

It happens in Firefox 17, and Safari 6.0.1, and Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94. Stack Exchange revision is 2012.10.20.4492.

Comment: Looks like a bug, since [similar bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147036/review-beta-first-posts-im-done-disabled-if-browser-back-button-used) was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this bug, but I remember fixing [something similar lately](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/pressing-back-and-forward-buttons-when-reviewing-leads-to-weird-behavior). Since that fix also included correcting the button handling when the editor has been loaded and the back navigation happens, it could as well fixed this issue.

Comment: Very likely it did fix this one too... but why don't you migrate that report here since it's affecting all sites?