# Content review issue

Tags: support, bug

I've run into a problem with the reviewing functionality on SO. I've noticed that while reviewing, if I hit the browser back button to the previous content on the review queue and then hit the forward button (back) to where I was coming from, the content (I've only observed it for questions so far) is displayed in full twice on the page, and the `I'm done` and `Skip` buttons don't work any more on that page. This I've tried 3x on Chrome v 22.0.1229.94 m.

Comment: Related, but not an identical situation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152089/the-browsers-back-button-cause-problems-with-the-review-buttons