# 'add/show # more comments' link broken after browsing back in review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, review, back-button

In certain cases, the link 'add / show # more comments' under a review doesn't work. I can reliably reproduce this when doing the following:

1. Open a review you have already done (or one that is completed). (You can use [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3322183) or [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3354107) as example).
2. Click the 'add / show # more comment' link. This should show the comments.
3. Click next
4. Click the back button in the browser
5. Try to click 'add / show # more comment' again.

This doesn't work. Inspecting the network tab in the developer tools shows that on clicking this link, 3 requests are made to the same page, all returning with 200 OK and all the comments in them. I am suspecting that somehow three click handlers are attached to the link, who all fail to properly update the comment section.

---

I originally had this bug when reviewing such an entry and clicking back. That's not really great to reproduce the problem though. I think step 2 and 3 can be swapped and the outcome would still be the same, but I couldn't test that just now. I had this bug in the 'close review queue', but I suspect this is the same for other queues as well.

Edit: [A similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152089/the-browsers-back-button-cause-problems-with-the-review-buttons) seems to happen with the review buttons. I don't see this as a duplicate of that question, because there are functions on the page that will still work (such as clicking the next button, or clicking this exact same link without doing step 2).

Comment: I think it can be considered part of [this bigger issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152089/152859) with using the back button in reviews. My advice: don't use the back button while reviewing.

Comment: It's a similar problem and probably caused by the same thing, but I wouldn't consider this a duplicate of that question.

Comment: My reasoning is that when the other issue will be addressed, yours will be fixed too so it's easier to link them together.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily have to be the case and therefore it should be a seperate question/bug, so devs who can look into the code can determine if this is caused by the same thing. After reading the other question a few times, I notice that the other question mentions opening an edit interface, which disables the review buttons. I suppose that the review buttons might not be enabled again when navigating back, instead of attaching multiple handlers to them.

Comment: yup, that was indeed another bug, fix incoming....

Comment: I simply do not understand why people mark this as a duplicate if even a SE dev says it is a different bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't believe me if I tell you that the reason for this was *once again* caching - this time in the client-side javascript!

Look out for a `2013.11.14.*` build number.