# Browser's back button doesn't work correctly on the "Global Inbox for a user webpage"

Tags: bug, global-inbox, back-button, mobile-firefox

My Firefox for Android (version 62.0b7) browser's back button doesn't work correctly on the [Global Inbox](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/28/new-global-inbox/) for a user webpage ([click here for your own](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox)) after you use the next or numbered buttons.

[image: These are the Numbered and Next buttons]

Once you leave the first page (by pressing next) pressing the browser's back button causes you to remain on the webpage chosen by the numbered or next button until you've pressed the back button a sufficient number of times to leave the webpages entirely, then you return to where you came from without going *back* to each prior page. It is as though no updated history is stored.

STR:

1. Go to [your Global Inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).
2. Press next a few times.
3. Press your browser's back button.

Notice you would remain on page 4, never revisiting 3, 2 and 1; upon the fourth press you would return to where you came from (back works correctly, eventually).

Expected operation:

You ought to be able to press any combination of next, numbered, and prev buttons and when you press your browser's back button you should go back one webpage. Pressing and holding the back button (to pop-up the history) shows all the back-links but choosing one doesn't take you back, instead you remain on the numbered page until 'you have exhausted your *backs*' then you jump away.

Note: There are other Bug Reports about the Browser back buttons not working in other situations but none regarding the Global Inbox. EG: [The browser's "Back" button cause problems with the review buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152089/the-browsers-back-button-cause-problems-with-the-review-buttons).

Comment: The same issue occurs with Firefox ESR 52.9.0 (32-bit). Interestingly, the correct previous page shows up in the location bar, but the page doesn't update. I'm assuming the same thing happens in Firefox for Android?

Comment: Yes. Also if anyone can reproduce this on different OS/Browser a comment here would be appreciated.

Comment: This bug doesn't seem to ***always*** occur on the user's 'Vote Page':  https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes - Sometimes the back button works and sometimes not - It seems to have the same UI (though the graphic for the buttons is different) so the code used on the votes page might be compared and used to debug a correction for the code on the user's inbox.