# Review Lists showing incorrect total

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

First, know that I discovered this on the game dev SE, but i think it might apply to many SE sites that don't have a ton of questions.

[image: Review Lists]

On the review tab I noticed the total next to each option to review.  Then when you actually click on one, surprisingly it would be empty.

[image: Review First Answers]

It took me a few moments to figure out that this was because it was on the day setting.  To actual match the total you would have to click the "all" button.  Essentially what I am saying is that this behavior is unexpected and maybe a more intuitive way of doing it would be to send the user to the page with "all" selected, therefor you wouldn't default them to seeing 0 posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These queues will eventually be replaced by "proper" review queues that fit well into [the new review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta). We won't be correcting the display of item counts for old review queues since we'd rather just build new queues out of them instead. :)

First Answers and First Questions are already turning into [First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts). Once the issues with the new queue are ironed out, the old ones should be removed and I believe Late Answers won't be far behind in one way or another.

Comment: oh wow somehow i ignored the top part and just looked at the outdated review, thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, that wouldn't be a good idea, especially on Stack overflow where those counts were (previously) in the tens of thousands (that's a lot of work to compile the list).

Aside from that, these panels are in the process of being replaced anyways, so you won't have those options *day*, *week*, *month*, *year*, and *all* anymore. Just a single post at a time, until the posts run out. Cheers, the counts will match up. :)