# Where is that post where they mention about new answers being moderated

Tags: discussion, support

There was some information about how the new answers are being moderated. Can anyone tell me where was that article?

Comment: Do you mean the IRA or the PLO?

Comment: Do you mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system - one of the suggestions on that question was to moderate new answers, but that wasn't ever implemented to my knowledge

Comment: How is this question still open after 3 hours? The only close reason that _doesn't_ apply is "Off topic".

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Review Queue: First Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts)

Answer (score 5):

Completely guessing here, but... this?

[New Review Queue: First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts)

If not, anything else you could remember from the post you're looking for would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean "moderated" in a typical forum sense where the posts are held until a Moderator manually approves, the post, then you're mistaken - edits to other posts are held for peer review but new questions/answers aren't moderated.

Having said that in here's some more info on the review queues

- [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta)
- [New Review Queue: First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts)