# First post answer is incomplete

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

So I was reviewing some first posts and came across an answer to a question that was definitely an answer, just an incomplete one that only answered half the question.  So basically it was an answer, and the "quality" wasn't low. What should be done in this case?

Should I flag it for review, or should I pass it and let users downgrade the answer?

Comment: Can you link to it? Without seeing it first, my inclination would be to pass on it. Maybe it's helpful only answering the first part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2077174 . It's not a great answer to begin with, but technically answers half the question

Comment: You can also write a comment to that effect.

Comment: It's a really bad answer (doesn't really answer the question at all), but guilty of nothing else really. I'd just down-vote it (or not) and move on.

Comment: So that's a "no action needed", or should the community decide?  and while this one might be a clear, what if it was better written but still incomplete?

Comment: In general, that would be a down-vote and a constructive comment according to the post written when the queue was introduced: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts

Answer (score 4):

I would've down-voted that one.

FWIW, this is one of those cases where glancing at the sidebar helps:

[image: metadata]

That question already had an answer. An accepted answer. An *old* accepted answer. A partial answer in this case isn't really helping anyone. Older questions often collect new answers that are either copies of older ones, half-assed attempts to answer something that's already been answered, or both. They *occasionally* collect really good updated answers. Hence the review.

Comment: Or attempts to get some rep...

Comment: Yeah, wasn't looking at those, that would have made this choice very clear... now I know

Answer (score 3):

I would downvote and leave a constructive comment - something like:

> This only answers the (1st|2nd) part of the [OP's][original] question. Could you provide the rest of the answer?