# Don't cap reviews based on vote limits

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, voting-limits

As noted in [the original announcement for the First Posts review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts):

> The only requirement to participate is the ability to cast both up and down-votes on the site, making this the most inclusive queue to date.

It seems wrong to block a user's ability to review First Posts and Late Answers just because their daily vote limit is reached. Therefore, I propose that...

**The ability to review posts in the First Posts and Late Answers queues be limited to 20 per day, with *no further restrictions*.**

If we want users to assist with reviews, they shouldn't have to consider how many votes they have left and remember to not use their last vote.
They should be free to use their own votes as they choose, and reviewing is a separate issue.

It should be simple, but a system is not simple (IMO) when:

1. A user with 40 votes in a day *cannot review*
2. A user with 39 votes in a day can review *unlimited*
3. Review votes *do not* count towards the daily vote limit
4. Votes outside review *do* count towards not being able to review
5. 1 daily vote remaining allows unlimited review and unlimited votes within review

That is weird - Voting out of review is limited; Votes within review is unlimited; Yet once out of review vote limit is reached, the voting within review is no longer unlimited, and is not permitted... ?

That one vote allowing *unlimited* review votes is illogical (it irks me, a little, too.. like it's a bug, I know it's not, but it smells like one. I licked it once, and it tasted like one, too).

Comment: @Shog9 How on earth is mine a dupe of that? That question's *only* suggestion is to "still allow reviews when daily vote limit reached, but not let users review  questions/answers which require voting". I never even suggested that one single suggestion the other question made. I also didn't ask why this is the case, I pointed out why I think it's wrong. I made all kinds of points and observations. Oh, wait, the title is *similar*...

Comment: Huh? You're describing the *exact same thing!* You have a different opinion on it, but the problem you're addressing is the same and *the answer is the same.*

Comment: Also, no one gets unlimited reviews. You max out at 20 regardless of whether you still have votes left or not. You might as well complain that the reopen queue doesn't let you keep reviewing when you run out of reopen votes.

Comment: The other questions asked why this happens. I already know and did not ask why. The other question has *only one* suggestion, which is not even a valid suggestion. I did not suggest it. As I did not ask the only thing the other question asked, nor suggest the only thing it suggested, how is mine a dupe? The other question's title is even a question, mine is a statement.

Comment: If you're making a change request, then use the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag, @James - and also try to highlight *what* you want changed somewhere. If you're not suggesting a change, asking a question or looking for help using the system, then... What are you looking for?

Comment: "You have a different opinion" I have a *completely* different opinion, different observations, new thoughts, stated things which the other answer not only doesn't answer, but *contradicts*.

Comment: Let's start over. What is the purpose of this post?

Comment: "If you're not suggesting a change, asking a question or looking for help using the system, then... What are you looking for?" For people to read and *discuss*. I stated "*just don't cap reviews based on vote limits*". Maybe I misunderstood the Discussion Tag: "*A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion*". Never mind. Leave it closed. It's clearly a duplicate as I'm talking about the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes, you read the description of the "discussion" tag correctly. But so far as I can tell, this isn't a *question* - it's a statement. So again, what is its purpose?

Comment: Its purpose is *Discussion*. Quotes from the post: "voting outside the review also shouldn't have any bearing on the user being able to review or not because of a daily vote limit" - "If we want users to assist with reviews, they shouldn't have to consider how many votes they have left and remember to not use their last vote" - "the system is not simple" - "That one vote allowing unlimited review votes is illogical" - "**don't cap reviews based on vote limits**". So is your argument now I've not asked or proposed anything? I thought the reason to close was it was a dupe?

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. But you keep insisting it isn't. Well... Then what *is* it? Look, I really don't care that much; if I'm wrong, explain how and we'll get this fixed up. Right now, I can't even edit this because I've no earthly clue what the hell you're going for. If you just wanted to rant about /review limits, you could probably do that in chat...

Comment: It really isn't a dupe just because the very basic and core subject matter is the same. Besides, how can a "non-question" as you have defined it, be a dupe of a legit open and linked to "question"? Close as "not a question" or "off topic". I don't want to continue to argue with you, as it's hard in comments to get a fair point across in limited chars without sounding terse or abrupt. Leave it as is. I disagree it's a dupe completely. And in the end was trying to point out a potential improvement in Stack, and wanting to discuss it to see if others agreed and potentially make an improvement. NM

Comment: If you want to suggest an improvement, then [suggest an improvement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) - then it won't be a duplicate and we'll have something to talk about.

Comment: "If you want to suggest an improvement, then suggest an improvement". I did an hour ago, throughout my post, and finishing with: "don't cap reviews based on vote limits". There are many "questions" on MSO which don't really ask a question, or make a real statement other than highlight various potential issues of a particular part of Stack, and do nothing other than allow community to discuss them. In those other questions, they get many upvotes and community answering and "discussing". I see no difference here.

Comment: I see someone who doesn't know what he want, as he can't explain it no matter how many times presented with a direct question. Fine - it's re-opened. And I've even gone so far as to edit in what you were too gutless to say. Now I'll go further and answer it and you can figure out where you want to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

Your "unlimited reviews"<sup>*</sup> scenario is silly: yes, you get unlimited (up to the 20-per-day limit) if you never have to take an action that is *itself* rate-limited; so what? That's true for anything!

- I can review "unlimited" questions in the close and reopen queues so long as I never vote to close or reopen.
- I can review "unlimited" questions in the suggested edits queues so long as I never approve or reject them.
- I can review "unlimited" questions in the Low Quality queue as long as those questions end up being of high quality.

In other words, you're suggesting that it's somehow unfair that folks get to do more when **there is nothing to do**. Or, I suppose, when they don't actually care about *what* they're doing, so long as they feel like they're doing *something*...

Which is the real problem here: if you're unable to perform the most basic actions in a given review task, *for what purpose are you reviewing?* We don't need warm bodies taking up space; we need folks who care enough about the site to *do* something when they see something good *or* bad that needs attention.

If you can't do that, then stop whining and go find something else to do for a while. We'll still be around tomorrow when you get more votes.

---

<sup>*I honestly have no idea what you were trying to say here, beyond the hyperbole of including "unlimited" in your post. Voting is subject to the same limits within review as without, as are all other actions with the exception of editing and *commenting* - so unless you're arguing that you want to edit and leave comments on 20 posts a day in /review after having used up all of your other quotas...</sup>

Comment: I was just trying to help the site. If you disagree that it's something that needs attention, then why not just downvote? I was pointing out something *I thought* was potentially confusing to some users in the system, and a little pointless in that being able to review up to the review cap when one daily vote is left, but not being able to review at all with no daily votes, seemed whacky. Sorry for not being 100% perfect and using the word "unlimited". No matter, you put me in my place for sure and I will "*stop whining*" and will "*go find something else to do for a while*". Thanks.

Comment: Writing is hard; it's easy to be misleading or confusing. Next time you're asked for clarification, just provide it - things will go much more smoothly for everyone involved.

Comment: I did provide clarification. Any way, I was trying to help, by raising a discussion on a *democratic* "meta" site to allow community to chip in. If I was wrong, then fine, downvote me, comment to tell me why, answer to explain why the system is like this, etc. But as I'm apparently perceived as "whining" and not trying to help the site using the tools the site provides me with to do this very thing, and as it's already marked as "status-declined", I guess that's that. Cheers