# Let me handle Close reviews despite running out of Close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, vote-to-close

On MSO the bug [I can still review in the CV queue after running out of CVs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258718/i-can-still-review-in-the-cv-queue-after-running-out-of-cvs) was reported and subsequently fixed.

I verified in the comments what the consequences of this fix were:

> [So...to be clear: If I'm out of close **VOTES** I can no longer review in the CVQ despite the 40 close **REVIEWS** I'm allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258718/i-can-still-review-in-the-cv-queue-after-running-out-of-cvs#comment62535_265859)

My assumption was confirmed.

This fix is wrong. Despite being out of close votes you can still review and vote for *leave open* which is even important.

The claim that after the *bugfix* the code now works as designed might be true, but how it worked before the fix didn't hurt, wasn't borked and for the handful of people that actively and on a daily basis handle close reviews it helped.

Can the bugfix that is part of a revision *meta > rev 2014.7.16.2379* and *network > rev 2014.7.16.1713* be reverted so it implements this feature request?

Comment: You're requesting a feature.  Feature requests should be tagged as a [tag:feature-request] and not [tag:bug].  If you found a possible bug, you should tag it as [tag:bug].  Unless you meant that the [tag:review] tag is inappropriate for a feature request involving a change to a review queue?

Comment: @rene "Worked as expected" is worked as *Stack Exchange intended it to work*, not how you *think* it should work. Stack Exchange intends for you not to be able to review in that queue when you're out of close votes, and it is currently working that way thanks to that fix. Ergo, it is not a bug in any way.

Comment: Before the bugfix there was a bug with the site in which it didn't work the way it was designed to.  After the bugfix the site works as intended.  You're requesting a change in the site's expected behavior, which is a feature request.

Comment: This has been raised for other queues as well, and denied there too; it is expected that you can do *all* tasks when reviewing. If you are out of CVs, you cannot do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't know that, with my number of flags I never run-out...but on Close votes it is always a gamble...thanks for the info.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you happen to have a link to a post for one of the other queues? I've looked through status-declined review posts but can't find one that describes that feature.

Comment: @rene: [Don't cap reviews based on vote limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222872)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did saw that one but I hope you agree my feature request has nothing to do with the unlimited-ness requested in that post, that is just a weird request...

Comment: There's also [Why review system disable the "First Posts" and "Late Answers" if I reached daily upvote limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149664) (still searching)

Comment: That last one makes sense and is more in line what we had...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: save one close vote. You can do as many reviews as you like (up to the queue limit) as long as you keep at least one spare.

IMHO, this is a good strategy anyway; you never know when you might encounter a question that urgently needs that vote... We try to make sure folks have more votes than reviews for this very reason.

If you *do* encounter a question that you must close, you'll have to wait for the next day to continue reviewing.

Comment: So maybe add a warning before using the last vote?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Users are shown a fairly prominent (in red) remaining vote count with every close vote. Looks sufficient to me.

Comment: It's on the close dialog, right at the bottom, @sha http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18005/please-let-me-know-when-im-running-low-on-close-votes

Comment: But... people are not reading! :-)

Comment: I read it, @sha. Although amusingly neither George nor myself need the indicator at this point as our votes are perpetually maxed out.

Comment: I'll be very careful with that last vote...I'll defend it with my life...

Comment: @Shog9 for some reason that's what I have in mind for moderator close dialog http://i.stack.imgur.com/s8SAr.png ;)

Comment: Today was the first time I miscounted...now I have done only 39 reviews instead of 40....