# Why is an answer shown instead of questions in review?

Tags: support, review

When I review a question on *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)* using Chrome, I select **Review First Question**.

Often I get **answers** to review too.

I clicked

[image]

This isn't bad, but still, is it a bug?

Comment: @RobertLongson what are audits?

Comment: @RobertLongson no , these were no audits.

Comment: That's tough! let me try.

Comment: @Rob so you haven't got any answers as First Post reviews other than audits? O_o

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The review queue is called [First **Posts**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts), that means you get to review **both** questions and answers:

> The items in this queue are simply the first questions or answers posted by new users (limited to those less than 30 days old).