# Cannot view certain review queues without having up/down votes

Tags: discussion, review, voting-limits

Apparently, when a user has reached their daily up/down vote limit of 40, they are unable to access the First Posts and Late Answers review queues. Why is this? When I go into the FP/LA queues, it's not like I only up/down vote, I also sometimes vote to delete or add comments, and I personally think that closing these queues to users that have used their daily amount of votes doesn't help anyone in any way.

Note that I can still open the Close/Reopen Votes, Low Quality Posts, and Suggested Edits queues.

Comment: With First Posts and Late Answers, I assume one of the nice options is to vote. Maybe you just want to upvote (to show that it's good) or downvote with no comment rather than do a more/less extreme action of flagging if it is not necessary. Or sometimes, a comment is not enough and clicking "No Action Need" could be lying

Comment: @AnthonyPham I would assume that that's why, but it's annoying especially since there's something in the First Posts queue that I can't open. :P

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146988/346654) the announcement of first and late answer queues that details why this is the case.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch Ah, that makes a bit of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, like I said in my comment, you should at least have your votes handy when you can't use the rest appropriately or just by themselves.

This is also found in [Shog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts) as found by @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch (that's a long username...):

> We're asking you to help introduce new users to the site - give them some feedback, provide some helpful edits, and flag problems for the moderators. This is your chance to be a part of the <s>S.W.A.T. Team of Nice</s> welcoming posse, encouraging the new recruits and helping them learn the ropes.
>
> The only requirement to participate is the ability to cast both up and down-votes on the site, making this the most inclusive queue to date.

Since votes are quite important and clear indicators of the quality  of the posts to both regular users and the brand new users, who are indeed curious about how the community thinks about the question. I mean, most of the new posts will get  a vote as they are usually pretty good or pretty bad. I'm not saying you have to vote on every post you see in the queue but I'm saying that you're probably going to be using them a lot in conjunction with your other powers (i.e commenting, flagging) [bold is mine]:

> Yes, there's about a 1 in 5 chance that the post **you're looking at will be utter crap, or at very least something you'll want to down-vote**. But it is just as important to provide some sort of feedback to the new authors whose **posts aren't terrible - whether that's an up-vote**, or a comment, or even a small edit that puts a bit more of a shine on their already-useful contribution.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.