# Why doesn't meta have First Posts review anymore?

Tags: support, review, meta, new-users

While looking at the timeline for an old question here on meta, I found that it was reviewed in First Posts ([yes, it does exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats)). There have been 21 reviews in total, the last of which was done in late 2012. Also, navigating directly to /review/first-posts gives me a 404: page not found error.

When and why was first posts review removed from Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: My guess would be it never existed, and that those posts were reviewed on the old meta so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very few reviews in that queue here were done for testing purposes only. There were 21 total reviews, all from staff, that took place all on one day over the span of half an hour, corresponding with [when that queue was first announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts).

The queue never existed here as a formal review queue that regular users could access.

Comment: And who's going to [ask](/questions/ask) the inevitable follow-up question: "Why don't we have a first-post review queue on [meta.se]?"

Comment: @3D1T0R I was just thinking that exact same thing! Honestly, I think we could benefit very much from FP and LA.