# Should we de-synonymize [first-posts] from [new-users]?

Tags: discussion, meta, tag-synonyms

I noticed that [first-posts](/questions/tagged/first-posts) is a synonym of [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users). While the term "first posts" can refer to the first posts made by new users, the words "First Posts" can also specifically refer to the review queue First Posts.

I think there should be a tag for the First Posts review queue, given that its mechanics are different from most other review queues (e.g. able to access with only 500 rep, a single review dismisses the task, can take any action or no action, etc.) and because we have a tag for the [late-answers](/questions/tagged/late-answers) queue, which has similar mechanics.

Should we de-synonymize these tags and redefine the [first-posts](/questions/tagged/first-posts) tag to clearly refer to the review queue (and not just general "first posts")?

Comment: Both late-answers and first-posts are queues that only exist on SO proper, right? I'm not opposing to de-synonymize but let's also discuss if we need that tag at all, here on MSE.

Comment: @rene No, they exist on all sites, not just SO. Only Triage and H&I only exist on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No review queues have their own tags. In fact, early on we decided that we *did not want* separate tags for each review queue, instead preferring the combination of [review] + some other tag specific to that queue.

The focus of most review queues already existed prior to the queue existing.

- Late answers have always existed, and there is even a tool to track new answers to old questions at /tools/new-answers-old-questions. The queue is just a method of *reviewing* that list.
- Close and reopen votes were always a thing. The queue is just a method of *reviewing* those existing votes to make sure they get seen.
- Low quality posts had always been tracked through the various flags. The queue is just a method of *reviewing* those flags and taking some burden off moderators.

The First Posts queue is not any different. How we treat and help new users learn the site and quality standards was always a thing. The queue just allows you to review the posts of those new users to determine if they need any help. Even the [announcement of the First Posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts) emphasizes the goal as helping to introduce new users to the site. Thus, it was determined that the combination of [review] + [new-users] would be ideal for referring to the First Posts review queue.