# Description of the "Other action" review option refers to "this question" in the "First answers" queue

Tags: bug, review

After the recent [change in the review queue workflows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/643262), the "First questions" and "First answers" review queues have four options: "Looks OK", "Edit", "Share feedback", and "Other action". The last option, "Other action", is automatically selected when the reviewer takes an action on the post, such as voting or commenting on it. In the "First answers" queue, the description of the "Other action" review option is (**emphasis** mine)

> You have taken one or more actions on **this question** and have finished your review.

as can be seen in the screenshot at the end of this question. In the "First answers" queue, this description should say **this answer** instead of **this question**.

[image: Screenshot of the "First answers" review options]

Comment: @Catija Per [a prior staff statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325329/377214), the tag combination here is the correct one for this review queue.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that argument makes no sense to me. First posts aren't necessarily from new users.  This question has nothing to do with new users at all, so the tag is a bad fit.

Comment: @Catija Perhaps, then, the synonym from [tag:first-posts] to [tag:new-users] should be removed, and an alternate answer posted to that question as to the current staff position?

Comment: @Catija I used "new-users" because "first-posts" is a synonym of "new-users". Something is inconsistent here...