# Where did those over 300k first questions go?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review

There is a *First Posts* [beta review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) task now. That one has currently about 34K posts. What stumps me a bit is that the old *First Questions* queue had over 300k posts in it yesterday. So what happend to the difference?

Comment: Either a lot of people did a *lot* of reviewing or they set a cut-off limit to get rid of some of the *really, really old* first posts that just never got reviewed and probably don't need reviewed.

Comment: Maybe high-voted first questions are not included too, since they are considered "good" already

Comment: Right now the old link still works on direct call: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The old /review page was based on reputation, and could actually contain *multiple* posts from the same person. At the same time, it excluded true first posts from folks who passed the reputation threshold [by some other means](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128255/include-101-rep-users-i-e-those-with-the-association-bonus-in-first-questions). IIRC, it was actually based on a 10K tool that existed previously, the more accurately named, "New Posts by New Users".

The new queue focuses *specifically* on **the very first post** made by a member of the site. The only exception right now is that posts older than 30 days are excluded - otherwise, everything else is fair game. If you show up and post a dozen answers on your first day, the first of these will still be in the queue - but the rest *won't be*.

The up-side of this is that it should be much more useful as a means of introducing new users to the site: rather than being clogged with posts from prolific but mediocre writers, *everyone* signing up gets one shot at fame.

The down-side is probably that it's less useful for *highlighting crap*. But at this point, we have better ways of handling that.