# Why was the size of SO's first post review queue reduced by two thirds in three days?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review

In the review area, the number of first posts was nearly 60K three days ago. It is now at 19K. Why it is decreasing so quickly?

EDIT :

Now, there are only 4 posts to review ! There have been nearly 40K review in 2 or three weeks because of the release of these new badges.

Comment: Apparently people are using the review system. There have been almost 2k reviewed today and apparently there was a whole lot more since you last checked.

Comment: yes but it was nearly the same number (60K) in the past two weeks.

Comment: Maybe they're getting more efficient at it. Why are you so fixated on how many there were yesterday or two weeks ago?

Comment: There were also new badges added to the review system in the past couple days; therefore, badge hunters decided that reviewing is actually worth their time.

Comment: I'm not fixated on that number. I am just curious why "reviewing" is now so popular.

Comment: The close vote queue, on the other hand, has been consistently within 500 items of 60k for as long as I can remember.

Comment: I dont't think my question was so bad ...

Comment: I agree. I up-voted, and don't know why people are downvoting. Glad you asked too, because I didn't know about those badges either.

Answer (score 11):

Uh, did you mistake the Close Votes queue for First Posts? In the *new* review system, First Posts has never had 60k items in the queue.

The new First Posts queue [launched with 34K+ items, down from over 300K in the old system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147031/where-did-those-over-300k-first-questions-go) — those have been steadily decreasing as folks work through them.

Comment: And the Close Votes queue is still in the 60K ballpark, so no magic happened recently.

Comment: Oh, sure, just point out that the OP's numbers were wrong to begin with, invalidating the whole question. Spoilsport.

Comment: yes maybe. the question should be "...queue reduced by two in three days?"

Answer (score 10):

At the time of this post there are `18,084 reviews all-time`.  So clearly, there weren't 40k posts reviewed in the past few days.  There haven't been 40k posts reviewed EVER.

My guess is that SO changed their algorithm for what posts show up in that queue in the first place.

At the time of this post the first review on Sept. 22nd (so over 3 days) is on page 173 (at 50 reviews per page).  That means that there have been ~8650 reviews in that time, which is quite a bit less than 40k.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the most logical explanation for this is the [New Community Review Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges). Since the release of these new badges, the review system has probably seen a flux of users trying to get them.