# Are there fewer posts to review?

Tags: discussion, support

Lately I've been doing some reviewing on SO in my spare time and there were more than a handful of posts, usually in the *k* range.

When I checked today... there were none.

[image]

I checked again in a couple of minutes and there were only 5, and very shortly none again.
This seems like a very high drop in numbers.

Did something happened with the review process or are more people reviewing lately?
This strikes me as a very odd thing

Comment: No there are to many reviewers.

Comment: Now, if we could only put a dent in the 'close' queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer by shog9 [to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148483/why-was-the-size-of-sos-first-post-review-queue-reduced-by-two-thirds-in-three) applies here as well.

As he says:

> The new First Posts queue launched with 34K+ items, down from over 300K in the old system — those have been steadily decreasing as folks work through them.

So yes, there are fewer posts to review because the community was finally able to overcome the initial queue and now it's just a steady trickle. Judging from the [first posts history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history) at the moment the rate is 50 posts that were reviewed in 30 minutes — quite normal.

Comment: @ЯegDwight sorry, I don't like that unicode symbol. I prefer the ordinary "-" character.

Comment: It's not ordinary, it's just wrong in that position. A [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) is not a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). This is like saying you don't like the letter B and using the ordinary D instead. Besides, the "-" is Unicode, too. *All* characters in your post are Unicode symbols. So your motivation for changing wrong into right doesn't even make sense. Lastly, the first dash is in a quote. As long as the original has the dash, so must the quote.

Comment: Yes, it's *like* saying that, but of a somewhat different degree...

Comment: And I distinctly have the impression now that the review queue has decreased review quality. :-( I see blatant spam being voted up, presumably just to have "I'm Done" button become active in the "Last Answers" queue, for example.

Comment: @ЯegDwight let's agree to disagree. I can't see any value in replacing all the thousands of "-" with "—".

Comment: @Sha who forces you to replace them? You don't see a value, so you don't replace. I do see a value, so I do replace. What's the problem? "I don't use proper punctuation because I don't like it" is a weird statement, but if you want to be quirky like that, so be it. However, "I don't use proper punctuation because I don't like it, *so I will prevent others from using it*" is a destructive attitude. It's sabotage.

Comment: @ЯegDwight I don't have "—" in my keyboard. I don't intend to open Word then copy&paste it every time. Since editing should add to the quality of the post and replacing punctuation marks does not seem like improving the quality to me, I object to such edits.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you object to more accurate punctuation, on the grounds that it doesn't improve quality? Even if other people are providing that more accurate punctuation for you? sheesh

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew if it's **only** this change then yes, it's too minor. If it comes with other changes like fixing typo or improving grammar then by all means, it's welcome.

Comment: @ЯegDwight sorry, I should have made a little research before deciding on my own what's proper or not. After reading [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen) I see your point. While I don't have anything other than the minus sign in my keyboard I can't really use proper punctuation, but I don't object to having it fixed in my posts.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew - same as what I told above to Mr. Dwight.

Answer (score 0):

> Lately I've been doing some reviewing on SO in my spare time and there were more than a handful of posts, usually in the k range.

All posts were reviewed by community(reviewers) before you came again here.

> I checked again in a couple of minutes and there were only 5, and very shortly none again

When new first posts are posted by new users then that posts come in First Post queue. And in very short time all queued post are reviewed. So you see X posts in First Post and in very short time it become 0 as all post are reviewed.

Comment: How does this really answer the question?

Comment: @slugster Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @hims056 It's not *wrong*, it just only states the obvious and doesn't discuss the details at all, which is what the OP seems interested in.