# Fewer first posts or more reviewers?

Tags: discussion

Is it only me or has it become much less frequent that one sees *first posts* to review? In [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149949/are-there-fewer-posts-to-review) there are already some indications but I'm not talking about them being low in numbers. I'm talking about the fact that I haven't reviewed any new posts since two days ago, I believe.

(And not that I didn't want to - there were none! Or maybe were for a short period of time but I have got me one of those work-thingies and need to attend that too.)

Comment: The overall post-count is dropping, is my impression. Something about a major holiday coming up or something..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure I follow your logic there... Holidays imply being away from work. That causes often an increase in free time. Surely, the only way to spend it is doing the old and half-forgotten programming projects one seldomly has time for due to work. That should spike up the frequency of asked questions because one tends to have forgotten certain aspects (especially when ones projects utilize a different technology than the one used in the daily work). So, no, friend. You must be mistaken. :) (Seriously though, it's a larger decrement i *FP* category. Why?

Comment: All the students are free from homework, all the pressing work questions are on hold until work resumes, and loads of people spend time with their family instead of with the computer. SO sees a drop in activity on weekends, Christmas time is just a bigger weekend.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was only joking in my comment. I understood the answer, of course. Thanks! :)

Comment: Okidoki, np! :-)

Comment: I just saw 2 in the queue and did one... So they're still about... Although do agree, they're definitely dropping off :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not privy to the top secret workings of the queue, but I suspect that the inner workings are parceling out the available posts piecewise to users that are currently accessing the queue.

In other words, at any given time, there is a steady stream of posts by new users, but the system is saving up 2-3+ at a time to release after a certain number of server "heartbeats".  Until it gets a sufficient quorum of posts, the count reflects as zero.  As the commenters have reflected above, fewer posts are being made during this holiday time, so the parceling is likely happening less frequently.