# Is there any analytics information that moderators can access for individual questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, moderator-tools, analytics

There are a number of questions on Programmers' that seem to be getting a lot of traffic:

[Do I need to go to a big-name university?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/35208/47)

[How to be a zero-bug programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/41248/47)

for example.

I'm curious as to why *these* questions are getting lots of views, while others aren't. So I'd like to know if anyone has posted a link on Twitter, Facebook, Reddit etc.

Can the referrer urls for individual question be made available to the moderators?

I'm not asking for exact and/or precise information - just the domain would do.

Obviously we'd need the a "most viewed" page in the moderator tools somewhere which would show these questions with a popup or link that showed the referrers for this link. A threshold of some kind for the number of views would probably be required to limit the queries made.

*(NOTE: I'm not discussing the quality of said questions).*

Comment: [Peanuts](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1893/over-243-000-views-in-3-days) ;-)

Comment: And what's with the referral links? If you used those by accident, then consider voting for [Privacy leak in permalink?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/we-like-clear-urls)

Comment: @Arjan - They weren't used by accident ;)

Comment: New related question: [Can we add moderator features to see keyword analytics and annotated traffic graphs for specific questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165593/can-we-add-moderator-features-to-see-keyword-analytics-and-annotated-traffic-gra)

Answer (score 11):

Using the existing analytics, you can narrow down the timeframe to a single day.  Our Google Analytics data isn't instantly updated, but once our data has been updated, you could narrow it down to just the single day and that's probably going to give you the referrers you're looking for.

If you're still unable to find the referrers or need a more specific url, and it's important enough for you to ask - then a Community Team member with Google Analytics access might be willing to find more specific data.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but if that's the way it has to be...

Answer (score 2):

I found:

http://topsy.com/programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/41248/how-to-be-a-zero-bug-programmer

http://tweetmeme.com/story/3685153041/career-do-i-need-to-go-to-a-big-name-university-programmers-stack-exchange

The university one was even twitted by hacker news.

http://friendfeed.com/newsyc/7b6943df/do-i-need-to-go-big-name-university

Comment: No fair!  I wanna be tweeted... :P

Comment: Indeed, [you do](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com/files/2011/01/6aSxI_thumb.jpg), @John.

Comment: @Arjan: Wow....

Comment: @John, and [that image](http://i.imgur.com/Kz5lo.jpg) is just the total pageviews for all of Super User. The views of that very question went up from zero to [243k in 3 days](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1893/over-243-000-views-in-3-days), and to [289k in 3 weeks](http://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for).

Comment: @Arjan: Again, wow....

Comment: (Secured the above-mentioned image [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x2dAJ.jpg).)