# Mechanism to track shares

Tags: feature-request, sharing

When I share a question, say to my facebook or twitter, it gets tracked by the site. (I know it must, otherwise you wouldn't be able to provide badges for successful shares!)

Would it be possible to get some feedback on those shares other than badges? If I know what shares were effective and what ones were largely ignored, it will give me better feedback to share most effectively. If I've put three questions on my Facebook about [topic-X] and they all only get 3 or 4 hits, while the three questions about [topic-Y] all got like 20 or 30 hits, I know that I should be more inclined to share [topic-Y]. But unless I get a badge for it, I don't know anything about it. Furthermore, those badges are only available once, so the long-term feedback provided isn't much.

I've only just started sharing posts, but I'm quite interested in getting this feedback so that I know how effective it is. I'm thinking it could be a tab in the userpage or something like that.

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-for-individual-questions

Comment: @Chris while not exact duplicate, it would appear mine would be a heavily shared subset. I would assume most people interested in this suggestion would also be interested in yours!

Comment: There are plenty of sites that provide this.  For example, you can go to Google and type in the name of a stock symbol (e.g MSFT, GOOG, AAPL, etc) and you can track how well your shares are doing right there in the results.

Oh wait, this wasn't about stock market shares, was it... :)

Answer (score -7):

There is the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer), [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/261/booster), and [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) badge for this purpose. The Announcer badge says: "Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days." That seems like a good enough metric. What in particular are you interested in?

Comment: You don't get that for each question though. Once you've shared a single post with 25 unique IP addresses, you never get feedback on those. I'm looking for a share-by-share breakdown of the number of visitors for each share, so I know which ones were hits with my friends, and which ones were misses.

Comment: I should clarify: I don't want badges, I want information on the effectiveness of my shares. Knowing that one of my shares hit 25 doesn't help me know which one did it, nor will it help me know which future ones did.

Comment: @glowcoder: If I am not mistaken, you can earn badges more than once and there is the ability to know how you got the badge. As far as misses, if you didn't reach the point of getting the badge for the question then you know it was missed. Though you do not know how many hits you got, for that you are correct

Comment: @Changeling I believe you are mistaken: it cannot be awarded multiple times.

Comment: @glowcoder: I haven't earned the Announcer badge, so I don't know - but I have earned other badges multiple times, such as the Nice Question badge.

Comment: @Changeling Badges that can be awarded multiple times say so in the description of the badge on its page. E.g. `"Nice Question     Question score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times."` Contrast that with Announcer which does not specify that ability.

Comment: @glowcoder: It should be suggested then!

Comment: It can be awarded multiple times now. No idea if that is something that was changed.

Comment: What if I want to know how many people visited my links to know how far I am from earning Announcer, Booster or Publicist?