# Can I see how many unique IP addresses visited from one of my links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

I shared a link to a question with a couple of co-workers.  A while later I got a badge for being an "announcer".  This caused me to look up the badge and I found there is also a badge for being a "booster" if it gets to 300 unique IP address views in 4 days.

Is there a quick way to see how many visits one of my links generate anytime I pass it around?

Comment: Not yet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94212/mechanism-to-track-shares