# How can I check the number of visited unique IP addresses for a post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mechanism to track shares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94212/mechanism-to-track-shares)
>   [Can I see how many unique IP addresses visited from one of my links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94525/can-i-see-how-many-unique-ip-addresses-visited-from-one-of-my-links)

Can we check how many unique IP addresses visited on any post by me?

I posted a question in my account, and I want to share this link to my friends on any other account like Gmail, Facebook and so on.
Are there any possibilities for check this?
This question may have been asked in another way, but I didn't get the solution.

Comment: yes, I already said that it can be repeated but I didn't get any idea above your provided links.

Comment: why there is no any counter like viewed for a post.

Comment: There is. Look at the right tab, between the tags and **Related**.

Comment: yes but this shows no of views means if a user view any post day by day from same IP then its increased by one. I thinks so. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no.

Comment: The views counter stores IPs for about 10 minutes, after which a visit from the same IP will count as a new visit

Comment: Don't vandalise your posts.