# Can I see where Publicist badges were linked *from*?

Tags: feature-request, publicity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mechanism to track shares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94212/mechanism-to-track-shares)

I've recently been awarded Publicist badge a couple of days ago, but I completely didn't notice. It claims I linked to the C++ book question (not a far fetch), but I can't imagine where I could possibly have dropped that link to garner so many views (and in a very short time). Is there any way to view the site of the link itself?

Comment: Furthermore, all three badges, "Announcer", "Booster", and "Publicist" were all awarded within a few hours. So it must have been a big.

Comment: Found it, you posted it in our super secret "Please delete this" Meta police mailing list...

Comment: You soulless bastards. Now I can never pointlessly spam links to my own questions to cue the Reddit hordes into upvoting me.

Comment: "I can't imagine where I could possibly have dropped that link to garner so many views" - You didn't. You're [this week's](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/09/are-there-any-general-techniques-to-speed-up-my-coding/) two-weeks-ago [Peter Olson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145673/why-did-i-just-get-the-announcer-badge-and-the-booster-badge).

Comment: Related: [Mechanism to track shares](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94212)

Comment: @TimStone That should probably be an answer. Whoever touched up that article seems to have graciously added the tracker IDs to all the links.

Comment: @Mysticial Yeah, it's a sort of reward for being selected to appear. Also, knowing where the post was linked from isn't technically an answer to this feature request to make that information more readily available.

Comment: Huh, at first I thought the Ars Technica URL thing was a mistake, but the tracker IDs match the poster, that's kinda cool of them (though I suspect we'll be seeing more "why the crap did I get these badges" meta posts :P)