# Expose data on view rates or google hits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, google

I think it would be useful to expose some data on either:

- View Rates (views/day, confined to say the last 3 months)
- Redirects from google

...for individual questions.

These are sort of "hidden" statistics that should influence how much editorial attention a question gets.  Just because a question doesn't have any activity recently doesn't mean it's not being read a whole lot.

How many questions do we have that are frequently viewed that could still be cleaned up and improved?

Is it possible to add a view to the toolbox that shows "High views in past month" for questions that were asked outside that timeframe (i.e. older than a month), or something similar for google redirects?

Comment: The [anonymous user feedback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) might be a way to get some of the information you're looking for already. For example, [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any analytics information for individual questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-for-individual-questions)

Comment: @ChrisF - It's similar but I'm worried more about **rates** than absolute counts.  I think it's possible/likely there are questions that get a steady 20 views a week that aren't high enough to show up on reports but still get a lot of exposure, and aren't getting editing attention.